# Make IDataElement from in memory featureclass

Tags: arcobjects

I'm trying to do some fieldmapping, but need to make a dataelement from an in-memory featureclass in ArcObjects to pass to the geoprocessor.

Basically, this line from the sample code:

```
IDETable inputTableA = (IDETable)gputilities.MakeDataElement(@"C:\Temp\k\tmpExplode.gdb\ExplodeOUTPUT", null, null);
```

But I there is no "real" path to the featureclass.  Also tried:

```
IDETable inputTableA = (IDETable)gputilities.MakeDataElementFromNameObject(null);
```

but I can not get to an IName for it either.  Has anyone made an IGPFieldMapping object from an in-memory featureclass before.  My code works fine with a file geodatabase layer.